# Display values of multi select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a dropdown menu, and multiple values can be selected from it. I have made it an autocomplete field using jQuery and that's working but the selected value is not being saved in this field. Also, i can't select multiple values. How to do this ?

---

```
<%= form.text_field :dropdown_values , {class: 'dev-rule-value-field', multiple: true, size: 20, style: ("display: none" if RulesHelper.method_type(@rule.entity, @rule.method) != "dropdown")} %>
```

The method called from RulesHelper gets the type of method basis which the contents of dropdown menu are curated (working fine).

**Javascript**

```
<script>
//code to get method_type works fine
    if(method_type == 'dropdown'){  
        $("#rule_dropdown_values").show();
    }
    var autocompleteProps = {
        let url = searchUrls[method_model];  // works fine 
        $.ajax({
          url: '/' + url + '.json',
          type: "GET",
          dataType: "json",
          data: { search: {value: request.term} },
          success: function(json){
            let data = json.data;
            if (data != null){
              if (data.length > 0){
                response($.map(data, function(item){
                  return { label: item.name || item.id , value: item.name || item.id , id: item.id };
                }))
              } else {
                response([{ label: "No results found." }]);
              }
            }
          }
        });
      }, 

      // select - not working 
      select: function(event, ui){
        let $autocomplete_input = $(this);
        // set value of text field as item label -- not working 
        $autocomplete_input.val(ui.item.label);
      }
    };
        $('#rule_dropdown_values').autocomplete(autocompleteProps);
    });
</script>
```

---

On the show page, i'm calling @rule.value, it works fine without the autocomplete but otherwise not.

Comment: Do you get any error (in Chrome and IE, just push F12 to consult the output console)

Comment: No errors on the console @StefGeysels